# Matlab Writing function for rectangle

Tags: function, matlab, math, plot, graphics

I have a homework, where I need to create a function in matlab which plots a rectangle. We can't use a rectangle function. We must define a own function.

I already coded some parts:

```
M=[1 2
   1 6
   4 6
   4 2];

x1= M(1,1);
x2= M(2,1);
x3= M(3,1);
x4= M(4,1);

y1= M(1,2);
y2= M(2,2);
y3= M(3,2);
y4= M(4,2);

x= [x1 x2 x3 x4 x1];
y= [y1 y2 y3 y4 y1];

function plotrec = prec(x,y)
plot(x,y,'g-o');
axis([0 10 0 10])
end
```

But the function doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a good place to ask a “I don’t know where to start” question. Do you know how to plot a function? A rectangle is four vertices, if you find their coordinates as an x vector and a y vector, then you can `plot(x,y)`.

Comment: yes but how can I define x and y ? cause i need the coordinates.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, if you don’t know where to start, this is not a good place to ask. I guess you need to start with a basic MATLAB tutorial? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html — I presume you know how the math works to determine where the vertices are?

Comment: I updated the question with the code I already have created. If you could have a look on it, that would be great @CrisLuengo !

Comment: Looks great to me! Adding the function call `prec(x,y);` before your function definition seems to produce promising results.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've already figured out what you needed, but in any case perhaps you will find this approach to the function to be helpful.

```
function plot_rec(M)

xmin = min(M(:,1))-1;
xmax = max(M(:,1))+1;
ymin = min(M(:,2))-1;
ymax = max(M(:,2))+1;

M = [M; M(1,:)];
plot(M(:,1),M(:,2),'g-o')
axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])

end
```